# How to pass the selected value as routing parameter from Razor Html.Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I pass the selected value/object/item from a datalist to my controller as the parameter?

Here is the razor code for my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Recipes")) {
    <input type="search" list=@Model.Recipes autocomplete="on" id="RecipeId"/>
    <datalist id=@Model.Recipes>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Recipes) {
            <option name = @item.RecipeId>@item.Name</option>
            <option value=@item.RecipeId></option>
        }
    </datalist>
    <input type="submit">
}
```

And here's how it looks when rendered:
[image]

And lastly the controller:

```
// GET: Recipes/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    RECIPE rECIPE = db.RECIPE.Find(id);
    if (rECIPE == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(rECIPE);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set your `input` `name` attribute becouse it's how you can differ your form values in request when you post:

```
<input name="id" type="search" list=@Model.Recipes autocomplete="on" id="RecipeId"/>
```